# Converting a csv file into a list of tuples with python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, tuples

I am to take a csv with 4 columns: brand, price, weight, and type.

The types are orange, apple, pear, plum.

Parameters: I need to select the most possible weight, but by selecting 1 orange, 2 pears, 3 apples, and 1 plum by not exceeding as $20 budget. I cannot repeat brands of the same fruit (like selecting the same brand of apple 3 times, etc).

I can open and read the csv file through Python, but I'm not sure how to create a dictionary or list of tuples from the csv file?

For more clarity, here's an idea of the data.

```
Brand, Price, Weight, Type
brand1, 6.05, 3.2, orange
brand2, 8.05, 5.2, orange
brand3, 6.54, 4.2, orange
brand1, 6.05, 3.2, pear
brand2, 7.05, 3.6, pear
brand3, 7.45, 3.9, pear
brand1, 5.45, 2.7, apple
brand2, 6.05, 3.2, apple
brand3, 6.43, 3.5, apple
brand4, 7.05, 3.9, apple
brand1, 8.05, 4.2, plum
brand2, 3.05, 2.2, plum
```

Here's all I have right now:

```
import csv
test_file = 'testallpos.csv'
csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(test_file, 'rb'), ["brand"], ["price"], ["weight"], ["type"])
```

Comment: Yeah, i got some feedback to change the title and clarity of the question. This is more specific and gives a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: then please delete the old question, no point in having two of them about the same topic.
Also please post your code so far, this will make people much more likely to help you

Comment: Yeah I deleted it a while ago, don't know if it takes a while or not to be removed. New to the site,  sorry!

Comment: All of the field names need to be in a single list, like so `csv.DictReader(open(test_file, 'rb'), ["brand", "price", "weight", "type"])`.

Comment: Does your file have the blanks as your example does?

Comment: My file doesn't, just used that for readability. Replace the spaces with commas and that's the csv

Answer (score 31):

You can ponder this:

```
import csv

def fitem(item):
    item=item.strip()
    try:
        item=float(item)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return item        

with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r') as csvin:
    reader=csv.DictReader(csvin)
    data={k.strip():[fitem(v)] for k,v in reader.next().items()}
    for line in reader:
        for k,v in line.items():
            k=k.strip()
            data[k].append(fitem(v))

print data
```

Prints:

```
{'Price': [6.05, 8.05, 6.54, 6.05, 7.05, 7.45, 5.45, 6.05, 6.43, 7.05, 8.05, 3.05],
 'Type': ['orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'pear', 'pear', 'pear', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'plum', 'plum'], 
 'Brand': ['brand1', 'brand2', 'brand3', 'brand1', 'brand2', 'brand3', 'brand1', 'brand2', 'brand3', 'brand4', 'brand1', 'brand2'], 
 'Weight': [3.2, 5.2, 4.2, 3.2, 3.6, 3.9, 2.7, 3.2, 3.5, 3.9, 4.2, 2.2]}
```

If you want the csv file literally as tuples by rows:

```
import csv
with open('/tmp/test.csv') as f:
    data=[tuple(line) for line in csv.reader(f)]

print data
# [('Brand', ' Price', ' Weight', ' Type'), ('brand1', ' 6.05', ' 3.2', ' orange'), ('brand2', ' 8.05', ' 5.2', ' orange'), ('brand3', ' 6.54', ' 4.2', ' orange'), ('brand1', ' 6.05', ' 3.2', ' pear'), ('brand2', ' 7.05', ' 3.6', ' pear'), ('brand3', ' 7.45', ' 3.9', ' pear'), ('brand1', ' 5.45', ' 2.7', ' apple'), ('brand2', ' 6.05', ' 3.2', ' apple'), ('brand3', ' 6.43', ' 3.5', ' apple'), ('brand4', ' 7.05', ' 3.9', ' apple'), ('brand1', ' 8.05', ' 4.2', ' plum'), ('brand2', ' 3.05', ' 2.2', ' plum')]
```

Comment: The last part of your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! 

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv
with open("some.csv") as f:
       r = csv.reader(f)
       print filter(None,r)
```

or with list comprehension

```
import csv
with open("some.csv") as f:
       r = csv.reader(f)
       print [row for row in r if row]
```

for comparison

```
In [3]: N = 100000

In [4]: the_list = [randint(0,3) for _ in range(N)]

In [5]: %timeit filter(None,the_list)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.91 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit [i for i in the_list if i]
100 loops, best of 3: 4.01 ms per loop
```

[edit] since your actual output does not have blanks you donot need the list comprehension or the filter you can just say `list(r)`

Final answer without blank lines

```
import csv
with open("some.csv") as f:
       print list(csv.reader(f))
```

if you want dicts you can do

```
import csv
with open("some.csv") as f:
       reader = list(csv.reader(f))
       print [dict(zip(reader[0],x)) for x in reader]
       #or
       print map(lambda x:dict(zip(reader[0],x)), reader)
```

Comment: don't do `filter(bool, ...)`, use `filter(None, ...)`, `filter()` has a special case that can avoid the excessive conversion to bool (since the result of calling bool is also checked for truthyness).   Also, don't do `filter(..., list(seq))`, just do  `filter(..., seq)`, filter knows how to iterate over sequences, the intermediate list just wastes space.

Comment: yeah not sure what I was thinking with the list conversion ... I didnt know about the None filter

Comment: Worthless use of `filter` You can just do `print [e for e in r]` which is faster and more readable. -1

Comment: please explain? those are not equivelent.... why is this a waste of filter? (See edit for timeit results)

Comment: The OP stated there were no blank lines in his CSV file. He posted it incorrectly. If there were blank lines -- you would have a point...

Comment: he had blank lines ... he changed it later (after I answered) in which case he can just call `list(r)` he doesnt even need a list comprehension

Comment: Thanks for the help! Playing around now that I've got the csv into something I can mess with.