# all rows from csv as tuples

Tags: python, csv, tuples

I am fairly new to python.

I want to read a csv file and store the content of as tuples.
This is my code so far, however I can't figure out how to make the tuples:

```
 import csv
 with open('apple_finance.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
 apple_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

 with open('new_apple_finance.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:
     csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',')

     for line in apple_reader:
         csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: `list(df.itertuples(index=False, name=None))`. This should be good enough

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Curious what is your goal with the data - does this have to be tuples?  [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776370/converting-a-csv-file-into-a-list-of-tuples-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can map the sequence of lists generated by `csv.reader` as tuples:

```
list_of_tuples = list(map(tuple, csv.reader(csv_file)))
```