# Is there a way to remove the 'quotes' a Python list has when reading from a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, folium

I am working with Python, using the Folium library. I want to read GPS coordinates (lat, long) from a .txt and throw it on a list. The problem is, the list I have right now comes out being:

`['(-27.414, -48.518)', '(-27.414, -48.517)', '(-27.413, -48.517)', '(-27.412, -48.517)', '(-27.412, -48.516)', '(-27.411, -48.516)']`

But when I want to use each item from the last as a location, I have an error:

`ValueError: Expected two (lat, lon) values for location, instead got: '(-27.414, -48.518)'`

Is there any way of changing my list so those 'quotes' disappear?

I have tried:

```
list(map(int, coordinatesList))
'[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, coordinatesList))
```

But to no avail, on both of those, the list isn't a list anymore and if I try to access the first item, it returns '['.

On my .txt, each line is a coordinate set (lat, long), with no parentheses and separated by a comma. I have a function:

```
def criaListaDeCoordenadas(caminhoArquivo):
    coordenadasLidas = []
    with open(caminhoArquivo) as arquivo:
        temp = []
        for latLong in arquivo:
            if latLong.strip():
                temp.append(latLong.strip())
                for i in temp:
                    i = '(' + i + ')'
                    if i not in coordenadasLidas:
                        coordenadasLidas.append(i)
    return coordenadasLidas
```

Which returns `['(-27.414, -48.518)', '(-27.414, -48.517)', '(-27.413, -48.517)', '(-27.412, -48.517)', '(-27.412, -48.516)', '(-27.411, -48.516)']`, but I want it to return `[(-27.414, -48.518), (-27.414, -48.517), (-27.413, -48.517), (-27.412, -48.517), (-27.412, -48.516), (-27.411, -48.516)]`, while still being a list. The return of that function is to be used on `folium.Marker()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a csv file into a list of tuples with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18776370/converting-a-csv-file-into-a-list-of-tuples-with-python) but also read about tuples in general, since not recognising that is what you want is the primary issue

Comment: @PeteKirkham thanks for the suggestion. I had looked into csv but it didn't seem to be what I was looking for.

Comment: @hyper "each line is a coordinate set (lat, long), with no parentheses and separated by a comma." if that is true, you have a CSV, just with a variable number of columns per line, which most of those techniques will accomodate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *creating* a string representation of a tuple, rather than creating an actual tuple, to add to your list. Do something like

```
import re


def criaListaDeCoordenadas(caminhoArquivo):
    coordenadasLidas = []
    with open(caminhoArquivo) as arquivo:
        temp = []
        for lat_long_str in arquivo:
            lat_long = [float(x) for x in re.split(r',\s*', lat_long_str)]
            coordenadasLidas.append(tuple(lat_long))
    return coordenadasLidas
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! I forgot tuples were a thing, been a while since I used Python.

Answer (score 0):

from the basic methods of python's data-structure , this can be easily handled. The resultant will be a list containing tuples, each tuple containing a  pair of latitude and longitude which in turn can be used in other applications.

```
l = ['(-27.414, -48.518)', '(-27.414, -48.517)', '(-27.413, -48.517)', '(-27.412, -48.517)', '(-27.412, -48.516)', '(-27.411, -48.516)']
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = l[i].split(', ')
    l[i][0] = l[i][0].replace('(', '')
    l[i][1] = l[i][1].replace(')', '')
    l[i][0] = float(l[i][0])
    l[i][1] = float(l[i][1])
    l[i] = tuple(l[i])
print(l)

#output:
[(-27.414, -48.518), (-27.414, -48.517), (-27.413, -48.517), (-27.412, -48.517), (-27.412, -48.516), (-27.411, -48.516)]
```